# Configure welcome pages on sites and subsites with powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell

I have to configure the welcome page for all my sites, and sub-sites.

Is it possible to add content in the welcome page ?
I mean : a little text, a calendar, and sections on the page's right side (like "links" or "Documents").

And all this, with powershell ?

I saw [Change default welcome page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12434/change-default-welcome-page), but it doesnt match exactly with what I want.

I want to choose my content, and why not, write it in my script, on in a text file beside.

Atm, I just have one idea, maybe it's possible with templates ... but I never go deep in the subject.

If someone knows any advices or link in order to help me, would be great :)

Thanks in advance.

Nico.

P.S : I don't want to change the page itself, or its url
P.S 2 : I'm with SharePoint2013 (but can't add this tag =/ nor "welcome page")